# Is Captain Jack’s theme music ever used in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, music, torchwood

So I was wondering if the theme commonly associated with Captain Jack in Torchwood is ever used in Doctor Who. I am wondering as it is part of quiz, and I didn’t want to include knowledge from Torchwood.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but for the life of me I can't recall which scene. I've checked some of the ones I thought it might have been (his first death in "The Parting of the Ways", running to the TARDIS in "Utopia", dealing with the helpless Daleks and Davros in "Journey's End"), but no joy so far.

Comment: Yeah I thought that surely it would appear, but couldn’t think where.